# Help creating simple wood table?

Tags: joinery, wood, tools

I am learning about wood-working, and I want to start by building something relatively simple like this to hold a TV. I will be using 2" x 6" wood.

What particular tools do I need for the joints? It doesn't have to be these miter joints if they're too difficult, but I would like it to have some nice joints. Since I'm starting out, I prefer not using a circular saw.

[image]

Comment: This question is actually quite broad and difficult to answer. There is more to a joint for this connection than is visible. and a number of ways to accomplish it.  I suggest that you start by doing some research on various kinds of joints, There are a couple resource books listed in the joinery tag wiki (click on the 'Joinery' tag and select 'Learn more'.  Learning about your options will help you decide what tools and skills you need.  IF you narrow your question you will get better answers.

Comment: As you mentioned you don't want to use a circular saw, how do you plan to cut your boards to size?

Answer (score 1):

Although this table looks simple, it's actually anything but. There must be some kind of reinforcement of those joints or some clever method used for hidden joints or fixings.

See this previous question about the same table:

[What might be stronger than a miter but still look like a miter joint?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1453/what-might-be-stronger-than-a-miter-but-still-look-like-a-miter-joint/1454#1454)

Comment: The second I saw that picture I remembered that picture.